# Stacking Position of a PagertabStrip

Tags: java, android-studio, pagertabstrip

I have designed an App with a PagerTabStrip menu. One of the Fragments is where the Pictures are selected. The picture can be moved all around the screen. The problem is that when I move the ImageView containing the picture, it goes below the PagerTabStrip menu and I would like it to go OVER the PagerTabStrip menu, I need a sort of z-index. I tried the "elevation" parameter but it doesn't work on different fragments or layout file. The fragment having the ImageView Pictures is in a different Layout file than the one for PagerTabStrip Menu, so I can't use the "order of the list" for the right stack order. What Should I do?

[image]